# How do I move a video object on the timeline?

Tags: video, timeline

I have 2 videos that I have brought into my scene as image planes. They play fine but I would like to have them begin on the timeline at different times, maybe one video at frame 1 and the other at frame 50 and playing together when the second one is introduced. Currently they both play at frame 1.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done. Just select your video clip and go to the *Material Properties* tab. You can also use the Node Editor.

There, you will see many options, including the <kbd>Start Frame</kbd> value. set it to whatever you want.

[image]

**Edit:**

You can simply just animate te vissibility of the video by selecting it's associated object, going to the *Object Data Properties* tab, and press <kbd>**I**</kbd> on your keyboard while hovering over the checkbox to animate the value.

[image]

Comment: My fault, I was not very clear in my explanation.
I would like the video to become visible and start on say frame 50 as opposed to frame 1 which when I add video clips are always on frame 1.
I tried the method you mentioned which is great to know but the video clip is visible on frame 1, it just doesn’t start playing until frame 50. Is there some way of having the clip start on frame 50 , lets say in After Effects  I would just drag the layer over, can I do something like that in Blender?
Thank you.

Comment: @Bob Check my edits, solves the problem.

Comment: @Bob also blender has a Video Editing workspace, so you can add the videos there and interact with it like after effects unless you don't want to move it in 3d space or do any high-level effects.